# PHP-FPM service not working after few idle days

Tags: php, nginx

I had PHP_FPM running on my computer, and last few Xmas days I left my computer into sleep mode, today I run into issue that process is not running anymore when I tried to restart it it said that file doesn't exists.

I use this command for running it up

```
launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.php56.plist
```

However file is there but I'm not possible to run it from some reason, anyone have some clue about this issue?

Note: ngnix works just fine

Comment: restart your computer or first `launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.php56.plist` and then load again or check status with `launchctl list`

Comment: @HQ5 I just runned update to latest EL Capitan version, and reinstaled php-fpm now it works. Thanks for hints!